# How to use Rank() for each column and get top and bottom 3 values

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi iam finding it hard to implement Rank() function, below is my sample table

```
id     category   value   volume
1      product1     0.4     0.5 
2      product2     0.9     0.6  
3      product3     0.3     0.7
4      product4     0.19    0.59
```

Now i want to give rank to columns "value" and "volume" separately and get top 3 and bottom 3 of each column, i am testing below code in firefox browser sqlmanager . but the query is not working.

```
SELECT Value, RANK() 
OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) AS xRank 
FROM (SELECT Value FROM product_achievment) WHERE xRank>=3;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) is not doesn't support `RANK`.
2. You have four different queries you must `UNION`.

So, following query will return desired rows:

```
SELECT * FROM product_achievement ORDER BY value LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_achievement ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_achievement ORDER BY volume LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_achievement ORDER BY volume DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Workaround for `RANK`:

If you need ranking information also, I suggest creating a `VIEW` with rankings:

```
CREATE VIEW ranked_product_achievement AS
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT() FROM product_achievement WHERE value<=t.value) AS r_value_a,
(SELECT COUNT() FROM product_achievement WHERE value>=t.value) AS r_value_d,
(SELECT COUNT() FROM product_achievement WHERE volume<=t.volume) AS r_volume_a,
(SELECT COUNT() FROM product_achievement WHERE volume>=t.volume) AS r_volume_d
FROM product_achievement AS t;
```

Then you can just `SELECT` from created view:

```
SELECT id, category, value, volume, r_value_a, r_volume_a
FROM ranked_product_achievement
WHERE r_value_a<=3 OR r_value_d<=3 OR r_volume_a<=3 OR r_volume_d<=3;
```